# Parse JSON for specific values

Tags: text-processing, json

I have this JSON file in a single line containing thousands of records and I want to copy out sections of it, corresponding to specific household names or card numbers.

Attached is a sample containing 3 sets of data. Each unique section starts with `{"card` and ends with `[]}`.

The unique searchable detail in each section is either household name `"38BA1234"` or card number `"2132312312333344"`

From the JSON file, I want to retrieve about 100 uniques details but it must be section by section, separated by commas. I have tried grep and sed, no luck.

```
{"card_serial_number": 58913, "household_uuid": "2133d032f4fb45d88198d39753f50635", "interventions": [903, 905], "qr_code": "{\"version\": 1, \"members\": [{\"firstName\": \"MUSA\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MODU\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"1985-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Male\", \"recipient\": \"Principal\", \"id\": 17327891}, {\"firstName\": \"SADIQ\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"2014-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Male\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17327886}, {\"firstName\": \"MUSTAPHA\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"2012-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Male\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17327887}, {\"firstName\": \"MARYAM\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"2007-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Female\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17327889}, {\"firstName\": \"FALMATA\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"1993-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Female\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17327890}, {\"firstName\": \"ABUR\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"2010-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Male\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17327888}], \"card\": \"2132312312333344\", \"householdID\": 4203050}", "household_name": "38BA1234", "compressQR": 1, "pin_number": "8119", "location": "Bidu llari", "recipient": {"picture": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA9LaWBQrkEj60UcjlqTa5//Z", "first_name": "MUSA", "last_name": "MODU", "gender": "Male", "document_number": "38BA1234_01", "fingerprints": [{"code": "Rk1S1AICTAVbKAAAA", "finger": "Forefinger", "hand": "Right hand"}, {"code": "RIBXAJHAAAAA", "finger": "Ringfinger", "hand": "Right hand"}, {"code": "bAECqARTmAAAA", "finger": "Middlefinger", "hand": "Right hand"}, {"code": "Rk1SACDyATbOAIARAUIzAAAA", "finger": "Thumb", "hand": "Right hand"}, {"code": "IEPAWrzAICEAX/sAAAA", "finger": "Littlefinger", "hand": "Right hand"}, {"code": "RAIBPARu6AEC/Ab/1AIBoAQhNAEEMARnJAEDGAWKSAED+AYu3AAAA", "finger": "Forefinger", "hand": "Left hand"}, {"code": "Rk1vAED5AOi9AIDuAFN6AAAA", "finger": "Ringfinger", "hand": "Left hand"}, {"code": "Rk1SACAyMAAAAAGkAEElASa6AICwAdD6AECZADaQAAAA", "finger": "Middlefinger", "hand": "Left hand"}, {"code": "Rk1SDaAXS3AECXAa8VAECzAFHkAAAA", "finger": "Thumb", "hand": "Left hand"}, {"code": "RkQGAEBRAdCOAEAVAYT9AAAA", "finger": "Littlefinger", "hand": "Left hand"}], "birthdate": "19850731", "document_type": "IOM ID"}, "card_number": "2132312312333344", "alternates": []},{"card_serial_number": 58923, "household_uuid": "6db84a1c50614b53b84fc67c581dbe7f", "interventions": [903, 905], "qr_code": "{\"version\": 1, \"members\": [{\"firstName\": \"HAJJA\", \"middleName\": \"FATIMA\", \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"1978-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Female\", \"recipient\": \"Principal\", \"id\": 17327577}, {\"firstName\": \"TOMA\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"2007-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Female\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17327575}, {\"firstName\": \"FANNE\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"2002-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Female\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17327576}, {\"firstName\": \"ADAMA\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"2010-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Female\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17327574}], \"card\": \"3424567891123242\", \"householdID\": 4202992}", "household_name": "2134A213", "compressQR": 1, "pin_number": "9438", "location": "Bidu llari", "recipient": {"picture": "/9j/4AAQIrq9NI21yNj25rp9Mb5V/KvOrHQi5c+tZdyvJ71q3A+XNZ9yMjIqabEZjjmnRgdaWVajU4Ix0rpJNC1YAitOF8isaJsGr9vJyM1EogaSPyOaKjTJOaKxegH/2Q==", "first_name": "HAJJA", "last_name": "MUSA", "gender": "Female", "document_number": "2134A213_01", "fingerprints": [{"code": "RkDWART3AECeATdrAAAA", "finger": "Forefinger", "hand": "Right hand"}, {"code": "dAEP/AICmAEaJAEBtAKChAAAA", "finger": "Ringfinger", "hand": "Right hand"}, {"code": "Rk1XAPWNAECbAJPGAEDUARAfAICwAKjLAEBxAN/fAIBXAIooAICrAHSAAIDGAVZwAAAA", "finger": "Middlefinger", "hand": "Right hand"}, {"code": "Rk1CwAYRwAAAA", "finger": "Thumb", "hand": "Right hand"}, {"code": "DxAcaQAIBbAF0DAEB9AQ4hAICEAQbLAICbARrcAECbAS/XAAAA", "finger": "Littlefinger", "hand": "Right hand"}, {"code": "RkAasHAIDyAIrpAIDFAbcHAIDnAJdoAIBgAQDAAAAA", "finger": "Forefinger", "hand": "Left hand"}, {"code": "OFVAIDHAQDGAIBLALCRAICVALdpAAAA", "finger": "Ringfinger", "hand": "Left hand"}, {"code": "Rk1SApSAEDRAE16AIDxAJvfAECvAYsJAEEMAQZGAICdAar9AAAA", "finger": "Middlefinger", "hand": "Left hand"}, {"code": "MASBrAAAA", "finger": "Thumb", "hand": "Left hand"}, {"code": "ID4ARTGAIB6AY8DAIC6AIHmAIDXAKTLAAAA", "finger": "Littlefinger", "hand": "Left hand"}], "birthdate": "19780731", "document_type": "IOM ID"}, "card_number": "3424567891123242", "alternates": []},{"card_serial_number": 579001, "household_uuid": "0444ed63908646a898148abcea00f2a9", "interventions": [903, 905], "qr_code": "{\"version\": 1, \"members\": [{\"firstName\": \"HAJJA\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"DANLADI\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"1990-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Female\", \"recipient\": \"Principal\", \"id\": 17321251}, {\"firstName\": \"FATIMA\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MOHAMMED\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"2014-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Female\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17321250}], \"card\": \"212323311232A213\", \"householdID\": 4201878}", "household_name": "08A00598", "compressQR": 1, "pin_number": "8141", "location": "Bidu llari", "recipient": {"picture": "/9j/4AAQSkrDLgXB5opIJBIMN1HeikB/9k=", "first_name": "HAJJA", "last_name": "DANLADI", "gender": "Female", "document_number": "08A00598_01", "fingerprints": [{"code": "XmwAIDHAYJLAIBuAMyNAAAA", "finger": "Forefinger", "hand": "Right hand"}, {"code": "Rk1SAEDoATxSAED5AYQNAAAA", "finger": "Ringfinger", "hand": "Right hand"}, {"code": "Rk1SACAMz6AEA2APSyAEBhAP69AAAA", "finger": "Middlefinger", "hand": "Right hand"}, {"code": "Rk1SACAyECPAG95AIC2AIXuAEEBAUbcAEAgAaDNAEAwAaXQAIDKAL5yAEAOAVurAAAA", "finger": "Thumb", "hand": "Right hand"}, {"code": "HAICwAXFDAIDNASDSAECzAavpAEDtAY/aAEBuAVE3AAAA", "finger": "Littlefinger", "hand": "Right hand"}, {"code": "AEETAXIhAEAsAV5mAAAA", "finger": "Forefinger", "hand": "Left hand"}, {"code": "AAAA", "finger": "Ringfinger", "hand": "Left hand"}, {"code": "ICYAXd3AECwAXcDAAAA", "finger": "Middlefinger", "hand": "Left hand"}, {"code": "RAEBPAcNQAICYAM2QAEE1AY7AAAAA", "finger": "Thumb", "hand": "Left hand"}, {"code": "Rk1S9AIDLATUuAAAA", "finger": "Littlefinger", "hand": "Left hand"}], "birthdate": "19900731", "document_type": "IOM ID"}, "card_number": "212323311232A213", "alternates": []}
```

Comment: Use a dedicated JSON parser, like [jshon](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/)...

Comment: Or [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Comment: Or `jsoncatcmd`; install with `pip`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response & help Jeff, Michael and The_velour_fog but I do not want it in typical JSON format. I just want the information as as a single line text, extracted according to the unique number. I do not want it in any other format. The sections will be separated by comma. I think the title is misleading

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your json is invalid. You've got multiple valid json objects separated by commas.  So you either have to treat each object as a separate json string or mount each object as a key on an outer object.
Here I have taken your json and mounted each object on keys `a`, `b`, `c`.

you can inspect your error by copy pasting your json at http://jsonlint.com/

so now the json looks like

file: `data.json`

```
{
    "a": {
        "card_serial_number": 58913,
        "household_uuid": "2133d032f4fb45d88198d39753f50635",
        "interventions": [903, 905],
        "qr_code": "{\"version\": 1, \"members\": [{\"firstName\": \"MUSA\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MODU\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"1985-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Male\", \"recipient\": \"Principal\", \"id\": 17327891}, {\"firstName\": \"SADIQ\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"2014-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Male\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17327886}, {\"firstName\": \"MUSTAPHA\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"2012-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Male\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17327887}, {\"firstName\": \"MARYAM\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"2007-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Female\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17327889}, {\"firstName\": \"FALMATA\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"1993-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Female\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17327890}, {\"firstName\": \"ABUR\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"2010-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Male\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17327888}], \"card\": \"2132312312333344\", \"householdID\": 4203050}",
        "household_name": "38BA1234",
        "compressQR": 1,
        "pin_number": "8119",
        "location": "Bidu llari",
        "recipient": {
            "picture": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA9LaWBQrkEj60UcjlqTa5//Z",
            "first_name": "MUSA",
            "last_name": "MODU",
            "gender": "Male",
            "document_number": "38BA1234_01",
            "fingerprints": [{
                "code": "Rk1S1AICTAVbKAAAA",
                "finger": "Forefinger",
                "hand": "Right hand"
            }, {
                "code": "RIBXAJHAAAAA",
                "finger": "Ringfinger",
                "hand": "Right hand"
            }, {
                "code": "bAECqARTmAAAA",
                "finger": "Middlefinger",
                "hand": "Right hand"
            }, {
                "code": "Rk1SACDyATbOAIARAUIzAAAA",
                "finger": "Thumb",
                "hand": "Right hand"
            }, {
                "code": "IEPAWrzAICEAX/sAAAA",
                "finger": "Littlefinger",
                "hand": "Right hand"
            }, {
                "code": "RAIBPARu6AEC/Ab/1AIBoAQhNAEEMARnJAEDGAWKSAED+AYu3AAAA",
                "finger": "Forefinger",
                "hand": "Left hand"
            }, {
                "code": "Rk1vAED5AOi9AIDuAFN6AAAA",
                "finger": "Ringfinger",
                "hand": "Left hand"
            }, {
                "code": "Rk1SACAyMAAAAAGkAEElASa6AICwAdD6AECZADaQAAAA",
                "finger": "Middlefinger",
                "hand": "Left hand"
            }, {
                "code": "Rk1SDaAXS3AECXAa8VAECzAFHkAAAA",
                "finger": "Thumb",
                "hand": "Left hand"
            }, {
                "code": "RkQGAEBRAdCOAEAVAYT9AAAA",
                "finger": "Littlefinger",
                "hand": "Left hand"
            }],
            "birthdate": "19850731",
            "document_type": "IOM ID"
        },
        "card_number": "2132312312333344",
        "alternates": []
    },
    "b": {
        "card_serial_number": 58923,
        "household_uuid": "6db84a1c50614b53b84fc67c581dbe7f",
        "interventions": [903, 905],
        "qr_code": "{\"version\": 1, \"members\": [{\"firstName\": \"HAJJA\", \"middleName\": \"FATIMA\", \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"1978-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Female\", \"recipient\": \"Principal\", \"id\": 17327577}, {\"firstName\": \"TOMA\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"2007-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Female\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17327575}, {\"firstName\": \"FANNE\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"2002-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Female\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17327576}, {\"firstName\": \"ADAMA\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MUSA\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"2010-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Female\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17327574}], \"card\": \"3424567891123242\", \"householdID\": 4202992}",
        "household_name": "2134A213",
        "compressQR": 1,
        "pin_number": "9438",
        "location": "Bidu llari",
        "recipient": {
            "picture": "/9j/4AAQIrq9NI21yNj25rp9Mb5V/KvOrHQi5c+tZdyvJ71q3A+XNZ9yMjIqabEZjjmnRgdaWVajU4Ix0rpJNC1YAitOF8isaJsGr9vJyM1EogaSPyOaKjTJOaKxegH/2Q==",
            "first_name": "HAJJA",
            "last_name": "MUSA",
            "gender": "Female",
            "document_number": "2134A213_01",
            "fingerprints": [{
                "code": "RkDWART3AECeATdrAAAA",
                "finger": "Forefinger",
                "hand": "Right hand"
            }, {
                "code": "dAEP/AICmAEaJAEBtAKChAAAA",
                "finger": "Ringfinger",
                "hand": "Right hand"
            }, {
                "code": "Rk1XAPWNAECbAJPGAEDUARAfAICwAKjLAEBxAN/fAIBXAIooAICrAHSAAIDGAVZwAAAA",
                "finger": "Middlefinger",
                "hand": "Right hand"
            }, {
                "code": "Rk1CwAYRwAAAA",
                "finger": "Thumb",
                "hand": "Right hand"
            }, {
                "code": "DxAcaQAIBbAF0DAEB9AQ4hAICEAQbLAICbARrcAECbAS/XAAAA",
                "finger": "Littlefinger",
                "hand": "Right hand"
            }, {
                "code": "RkAasHAIDyAIrpAIDFAbcHAIDnAJdoAIBgAQDAAAAA",
                "finger": "Forefinger",
                "hand": "Left hand"
            }, {
                "code": "OFVAIDHAQDGAIBLALCRAICVALdpAAAA",
                "finger": "Ringfinger",
                "hand": "Left hand"
            }, {
                "code": "Rk1SApSAEDRAE16AIDxAJvfAECvAYsJAEEMAQZGAICdAar9AAAA",
                "finger": "Middlefinger",
                "hand": "Left hand"
            }, {
                "code": "MASBrAAAA",
                "finger": "Thumb",
                "hand": "Left hand"
            }, {
                "code": "ID4ARTGAIB6AY8DAIC6AIHmAIDXAKTLAAAA",
                "finger": "Littlefinger",
                "hand": "Left hand"
            }],
            "birthdate": "19780731",
            "document_type": "IOM ID"
        },
        "card_number": "3424567891123242",
        "alternates": []
    },
    "c": {
        "card_serial_number": 579001,
        "household_uuid": "0444ed63908646a898148abcea00f2a9",
        "interventions": [903, 905],
        "qr_code": "{\"version\": 1, \"members\": [{\"firstName\": \"HAJJA\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"DANLADI\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"1990-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Female\", \"recipient\": \"Principal\", \"id\": 17321251}, {\"firstName\": \"FATIMA\", \"middleName\": null, \"lastName\": \"MOHAMMED\", \"dateOfBirth\": \"2014-02-14\", \"gender\": \"Female\", \"recipient\": \"\", \"id\": 17321250}], \"card\": \"212323311232A213\", \"householdID\": 4201878}",
        "household_name": "08A00598",
        "compressQR": 1,
        "pin_number": "8141",
        "location": "Bidu llari",
        "recipient": {
            "picture": "/9j/4AAQSkrDLgXB5opIJBIMN1HeikB/9k=",
            "first_name": "HAJJA",
            "last_name": "DANLADI",
            "gender": "Female",
            "document_number": "08A00598_01",
            "fingerprints": [{
                "code": "XmwAIDHAYJLAIBuAMyNAAAA",
                "finger": "Forefinger",
                "hand": "Right hand"
            }, {
                "code": "Rk1SAEDoATxSAED5AYQNAAAA",
                "finger": "Ringfinger",
                "hand": "Right hand"
            }, {
                "code": "Rk1SACAMz6AEA2APSyAEBhAP69AAAA",
                "finger": "Middlefinger",
                "hand": "Right hand"
            }, {
                "code": "Rk1SACAyECPAG95AIC2AIXuAEEBAUbcAEAgAaDNAEAwAaXQAIDKAL5yAEAOAVurAAAA",
                "finger": "Thumb",
                "hand": "Right hand"
            }, {
                "code": "HAICwAXFDAIDNASDSAECzAavpAEDtAY/aAEBuAVE3AAAA",
                "finger": "Littlefinger",
                "hand": "Right hand"
            }, {
                "code": "AEETAXIhAEAsAV5mAAAA",
                "finger": "Forefinger",
                "hand": "Left hand"
            }, {
                "code": "AAAA",
                "finger": "Ringfinger",
                "hand": "Left hand"
            }, {
                "code": "ICYAXd3AECwAXcDAAAA",
                "finger": "Middlefinger",
                "hand": "Left hand"
            }, {
                "code": "RAEBPAcNQAICYAM2QAEE1AY7AAAAA",
                "finger": "Thumb",
                "hand": "Left hand"
            }, {
                "code": "Rk1S9AIDLATUuAAAA",
                "finger": "Littlefinger",
                "hand": "Left hand"
            }],
            "birthdate": "19900731",
            "document_type": "IOM ID"
        },
        "card_number": "212323311232A213",
        "alternates": []
    }

}
```

If you have PHP installed you could do something like:

file: `parse.php`

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('data.json');

$data_obj = json_decode($json);

/* var_dump($data_obj); */

foreach ( $data_obj as $key => $value ) {
    echo $data_obj->{$key}->household_name . PHP_EOL;
    echo $data_obj->{$key}->card_number . PHP_EOL;
}
```

from the command line if you run the php script it will output the keys you are targeting:

```
php parse.php
```

output:

```
38BA1234
2132312312333344
2134A213
3424567891123242
08A00598
212323311232A213
```

then you should be able to use your normal grep, sed commands etc

Answer (score 1):

Using something like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to extract the household names and card numbers:

```
$ jq -r '.[]|[.household_name,.card_number]|@tsv' data.json
38BA1234        2132312312333344
2134A213        3424567891123242
08A00598        212323311232A213
```

This is assuming the data is a proper JSON array of objects.  The `jq` command will create an array of the household name and card number for each object and then print it as a couple of tab-separated values.

You could easily add the other field that you'd like to extract in a similar manner.